# POST'ing multipart data based on previously retrieved "binary" data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to simulate a file upload to a webserver that accepts "normal" file upload http requests but iso getting the file data using the typical input type=file form element I would like the POST'ed content to come from the result of a previous http GET

I think I have the GET part done using something like

```
function load_binary_resource(url) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', url, false);
    req.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
    req.send(null);
    if (req.status != 200) {
        return '';
    }
    return req.responseText;
}
```

Question now is how I can POST this so that the server code that acceptsa more typical file upload HTTP request can stay the same.

I have been trying with the jQuery forms plugin but I can't seem to get the binary content POST'ed to the server

All help certainly warmly welcomed!

Thanks

Peter

Comment: I read your first paragraph twice, but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Thanks for having the patience :) What I want is do a GET on a first URL retrieving an image and POST that image back to a second url (same domain) as if it where a "normal" file upload. Basically a copy operation I guess.

Comment: Can't you just hand the image URL over to the server and do the image download on the server side?

Comment: Marcel - thanks for the suggestion. I would indeed go that way if I could control the server part. Unfortunately I can not.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, and unless I'm mistaken, you can't natively upload files cross browser using an XMLHttpRequest yet.  It's possible with Firefox right now I believe.

I found these helpful when looking into the same thing:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_files_from_web_applications
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/File.getAsBinary

I've seen a few workarounds for sendAsBinary for non gecko browsers however I'm sure others know more on that front.  I abandoned something fairly similar as my targeted browsers included IE.  I ended up using Uploadify which will automatically switch to Flash or other methods when pure javascript methods are not available.

Hope that helps (or is even remotely close to what you're asking)

Comment: Thanks Jason. It is indeed close to what I need to do. I found some inspiration on http://en.dogeno.us/2011/04/post-to-appengine-blobstore-using-ajax-firefox-and-chrome/ . That is working on Firefox and Chrome but not on Safari. I have not even bothered about IE. Weird this is so difficult. I am doing my first steps in JS development.